# Cross compiling cross-compiler for Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compilation

I want to build programs with `distcc` on a Raspberry Pi for my desktop (x86-64).

My idea:

1. Build `crossdev-ng` on my desktop.
2. Build cross-compiler on my desktop to run on desktop and generate code for Pi.
3. Build cross-compiler on my desktop to run on Pi and generate code for desktop with `gcc` from step 2.

How to do the last action? Is it a right way?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? Your desktop is obviously capable of compiling its own code.

Comment: @DavidYaw, I want to use distcc with three hosts: desktop, notebook and Pi.

Comment: If you're setting up a cross-compilation environment to compile ARM on your x86, then just follow those same instructions to set up a cross-compilation environment to compile x86 on your Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cnadian build type. Now, you have got directory with name like `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi` (I call it cross-prefix). In configuration menu select `Toolchain options`, then `Type`, select `Canadian`. After this action, you can see `Host system` section! Enter cross-prefix (`aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi` in my case) into `Tuple` option (`Host system` section, NOT `build system`). Apply other changes (change target architecture to x86, etc.) and exit with saveing changes. Now, you need to add path to crosscompiler binares in your PATH. Run

```
export PATH="${PATH}:cross-prefix/bin"
```

Ok, tolchain is ready to build!